# SELECT ... INTO a variable within a postgres CTE

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, select-into

I want to do this inside a plpgsql function

```
WITH set1 AS (

  select * 
  from table1
  where ... -- reduce table1 to the small working set once for multiple reuse

), query_only_for_select_into AS (

  select id 
  into my_variable_declared_earlier
  from set1 
  where foo = 'bar'
  
)
select my_variable_declared_earlier as my_bar
  , *
from set1
where foo <> 'bar'
```

but Postgres throws the error

```
ERROR:  SELECT ... INTO is not allowed here
```

I'm guessing it's because the `select ... into` is in the CTE. But I can't find anything in the documentation or on the web about it. Maybe I just messed up the `select ... into` syntax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SQL has no variables - they are part of a procedural language (e.g. PL/pgSQL), not the query language.

But I don't see the reason why you need one:

```
WITH set1 AS (

  select * 
  from table1
  where ... -- reduce table1 to the small working set once for multiple reuse

), query_only_for_select_into AS (
  select id as my_variable_declared_earlier
  from set1 
  where foo = 'bar'
)
select qs.my_variable_declared_earlier as my_bar,
       *
from set1
  join query_only_for_select_into qs on ...
where foo <> 'bar'
```

If you are certain that `query_only_for_select_into` only returns a single row, you can use:

```
select qs.my_variable_declared_earlier as my_bar,
       *
from set1
  cross join query_only_for_select_into qs
where foo <> 'bar'
```

Comment: You're quite right... I forgot to mention that this was inside a plpgsql function. I amended the question. I ended up also doing `query_only_for_select_into` like you have it, but  I had some intuition that that a cross join (even with a single row, which I do have) would be slower than a variable reference in the select, hence the question.

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT ... INTO variable` is PL/pgSQL syntax, and you can only use it with the top level `SELECT` (the one that returns results. Think of it like that: PL/pgSQL runs an SQL statement and stores the result somewhere.

But you don't need that: simply include `query_only_for_select_into` in the `FROM` clause of the main query, then you can access its columns there.